# div doesnt display correctly on mobile view

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `div` which I show after button is clicked. This `div` is overlapped on other `div` and I display it like a popup. Although it looks good on desktop browser but doesn't look good when I select device mode as iPhone 6.

```
<div class="row" id="divPopUp" runat="server" style="height: 50px; background-color: red;  text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 30px; color: white; position: fixed; width: 35%; margin-top: 45px; margin-left: 40px;padding-top: 5px">Thanks for help</div>
<div class="row" id="staticdiv">
    Some text and image
</div>
```

The `div` named `divPopUp` I am trying to put on top of `div` called `staticdiv`. It looks good on desktop browser but looks very messed when viewed in device mode set to iPhone for example. I am using bootstrap. What can I do to fix this so it looks good on iPhone as well.

Comment: can you post you styles along with your code or else a working fiddle will b helpful.

Comment: @Benjamin Its bit difficult to create fiddle as there is server side code gets populated

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion you've set its `width` to *35%*, have you reset it for device view ?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay no how i set it for device view?

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

Previous **HTML**:

```
<div class="row" id="divPopUp" runat="server" style="height: 50px; background-color: red;  text-align: center; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 30px; color: white; position: fixed; width: 35%; margin-top: 45px; margin-left: 40px;padding-top: 5px">Thanks for help</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```css
.popup-block {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F00;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    width: 35%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
}


 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
       
       .popup-block { width: 94%; /* Or whatever floats your boat*/ }

 }
```

```html
  <div class="row popup-block" id="divPopUp" runat="server">Thanks for help</div>
```

Hope doing this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hey thats great. Just that div has moved bit to right when viewed in mobile view. What is this max-width:767px? So how exactly does this work? Is it possible to move div to bit left on mobile view?

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion you should study about [**Media Queries**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices), And yes we can change its `position` and anything regarding **CSS**, just using right selector in `media-query`

Comment: can you tell how to use right selector? I tried like .popup-block { width: 94%; margin-left:1px }      but doesnt work

Comment: Plus one for encouraging use of `media-query`

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion I've edited my answer, it seems by changing a little in your **CSS**, you'll have a better view. Try this and check for both Desktop as well as Mobile Devices

Comment: it messes desktop a lot and no effect in mobile view

Comment: do you have any Link?

Comment: its on my local env so not sure how can i give it

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion its running fine on Snippet, rest you can do is, set its `postion` from the top as `top: 35%` as per your need, but from *messes desktop* I can't understand anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91390/discussion-between-vivekkupadhyay-and-developmentismypassion).